# Insert numeration just for visible element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have five `div` some of them with `display:block` and others with `display:none`, and it changes dynamically.
I'm trying to add title with numeration just for visible elements.
For example, If I have two visible elements, I should have "seance 1" for the first and "seance 2" for the second, but actually I have "seance 2" for both. This is my code:

```js
$('#save').click(function() {
  var countVisible = $('.panel-title:visible').length;
  $('.panel-title').filter(':visible').each( function () {
    for (i=0; i<countVisible; i++){
      $(this).text('seance'+(i+1));
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="panel" style="display:none;" id="seance1">
  <h4 class="panel-title"></h4>
</div>
<div class="panel" style="display:block;" id="seance2">
  <h4 class="panel-title">text text</h4>
</div>
<div class="panel" style="display:none;" id="seance3">
  <h4 class="panel-title"></h4>
</div>
<div class="panel" style="display:none;" id="seance4">
  <h4 class="panel-title"></h4>
</div>
<div class="panel" style="display:block;" id="seance5">
  <h4 class="panel-title">text text</h4>
</div>
<button id="save">save</button>
```

Comment: You have two loops, first `each()` and then `for()`. It's because it fails.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do not add for loop. jquery each is enough

```
$('#save').click(function() {
    $('.panel-title').filter(':visible').each( function (i) {
      $(this).text('seance'+(i+1));
    });
  });
```

Fiddle -- https://jsfiddle.net/fkbqdepo/

Answer (score 0):

if i understand your question correctly it should be like this

```
$('#save').click(function() {
  $('.panel-title:visible').each(function(index) {
      $(this).text('seance'+(index+1));
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('#save').click(function() {
  $('.panel-title:visible').each( function (i) {
    $(this).text('seance '+(i+1) );
  });
});
```